# what is the effecient way to search a phrase in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, search, knuth-morris-pratt

What is the best way to search a phrase that have words that dont all matches, for example:

```
description = "a cell phone that have an external memory"
```

and i want to search:

```
search = "a good phone"
```

is there any tips using mongodb, or do i use Knuth-Morris-Pratt string matching from python (which will kill the server)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple regular expression search of a mongo db field you can use `find` with the `"$regex"` query expression.

In pymongo that would be `db.your_collection.find({"description": {"$regex": "<insert regex here>"}})`.

This will get you started. As others have stated, MongoDB doesn't necessarily appreciate you beating it up like this. You may need to consider a more robust solution for big time searching.

**Please consider the performance implications of doing a regular expression search in your DB.**

Read the MongoDB reference here http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions.

Comment: yes, regular expression will "kill" the server! espetialy when i use blocking library!
so the design of mongodb will not let full text search! only hacks! :(

Comment: Yes and no. You should limit the records you are searching.Perform your search on that subset. Are you searching every phone's `description` in the system or can you reduce it by manufacturer or user. If you must do a search on the full dataset, you will need a much more robust solution. @Phillip has an interesting take that involves reducing the set in another way.

Comment: it's just an option to the user, because i've included searching by "usernam" searching by "geo coordonates", and searching using "exact location", so the user will have a lot of result and choose.

Answer (score 4):

MongoDB isn't really geared for such shannenigans. I would recommend using an external service like [SphinxSearch](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for your searching needs.

Comment: thank you
am new in the DB world, and i've found people talking about Elasticsearch because it's the only one that has "connection" with mongodb? or do i got outdated information?

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp I'm sure it's quite good as well. I use a design pattern where I add the appropriate database items to the search store separately, and have derived great benefit from having them loosely coupled. You can thus process docs to a form specifically geared for searching (only adding certain fields, processing others, etc.).

Comment: so, i must "replicate" the data?

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp Yea I do this with Sphinx. I replicate the data between a Mongo instance and a MySQL instance, it is great. MySQL handles the weighty delta indexing etc leaving mongo to do its job of serving delicious data to the user in peace and quiet.

Comment: @Sammaye so why then using Mongodb to gain performance (sharding, failover, super fast querying...)

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp MongoDB is awesome as a storage engine but that does not mean it is a search tech. Search techs and storage egnines should not be confused. There is a clear difference between the two and you shouldnt mix them up. In Sphinx MySQL is only used as the data provider, it is not the actual search index. That is still it's own DB. Sincde delta indexing is heavy on any DB it is good to split it from the main processing your sites data so as to gain the most performance out of any DB.

Comment: am sorry, because i dont get the idea of duplicating data, how the sharding will be managed? (am a beginner, so sorry)

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp The sharding will normally be managed by the search tech or in my personal case both the search tech and MySQL. ElasticSearch infact comes built in with easy sharding thats literally a single command. Really nice.

Comment: so this is what is called in NoSql "Polyglot persistence", because heere it's MongoDB, Redis, and now ES :D
thank you ;)

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp keep in mind though that you're generally not just replicating the data. You store what you need and how you need it for each use-case in your app.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) to build a search index and then search in the resulting collection.

Your map function would first split the description into individual words. Very common words like "a" or "the" should be discarded. Then it would do an emit per word. *Key* is the word and *value* is the _id of the currently processed document.

Your reduce function would then be used to collect all documents which contain each word. It would return the key with all arrays merged into one and duplicates removed.

The resulting collection of this MapReduce job would then contain one document for each individual word which appears in the descriptions. These documents would contain the word and an array with the _id's of the documents where it appears. When you add an index you can search it very quickly.

This MapReduce job needs to be performed once to build the search index. This will take a while when you already have a lot of data in the database. Whenever a document is added or removed or when a description of a document was changed, you have to perform an incremental MapReduce to update the search index. This incremental MapReduce will be much faster than the initial one, so it should be feasible to do that automatically.

Comment: does it the main thing as description.split() directly in python?

Answer (score 2):

No one here has actually referenced the doc page on searching: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo

A good way of avoiding methods which will not scale such as Map Reduce and Regex is to actually store an array of keywords within your doc.

You would decide how you wish to infix etc words and what stop words you would want to remove and once done you would just shove that into a big array in the doc itself.

Map reduce is sometimes considered a bad way of doing this because it just won't for performance and threading reasons and regex because it has very bad use of index in 90% of the cases unless prefixed. I have seen a simple regex kill a lot of mongodb servers so I know just how bad it can be untamed.

I do agree with everyone else though that you should really look into a external FTS tech. I personnaly adore Sphinx: http://sphinxsearch.com/ for its speed, scalability and flexibility. However I have used other search techs like Solr and they are all pretty darn good.

Comment: that what i did finally, i've converted the text (maximum 160 characters to a set(list(array)) so i convert all the words to tags, but still cant access them! it give me error!
i'll make a new post about this error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437849/how-to-query-an-element-from-a-list-in-pymongo

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add a plug for [Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org).  They have a ton of [client libraries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/appendix/clients.html), including several for python.

Both Solr and ElasticSearch are built on Apache Lucene, but ElasticSearch has some advantages over Solr, IMO, starting with the fact that it speaks JSON instead of XML.

Comment: am sorry for this question, but how do i do? do i use python library to get the "description" from database, and the search the "search" in ES ?

Answer (score 0):

mongo 3.0+: just use text index on the field with the phrase. 
https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/index-text/